# How to prevent HTML5 Drag and Drop ghost image transparency gradient?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am working on a drag and drop feature for a list of tiles. I played with changing the ghost image displayed while dragging by changing the DataTransfer drag image. What I do is I clone the dragged element, append it to the body, hide the clone, and call `event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(clone, 0, 0);`, as it is described on [this site](https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html).

Everything works fine, but I realized that when the cloned element is too large, the ghost image is forced into some kind of "transparency gradient", and I can't find any way to disable this behavior.

Here's an example of the problem :

If the element's width or height is less or equal to 225px, we get a 'solid' translucent ghost image (This is the behavior I want) :

[Example of a ghost image under 225px dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kOSu.png)

But if the element's width or height is greater than 225px, we get a ghost image with some kind of "transparency gradient" applied to it (This is the undesired behavior) :

[Example of a ghost image over 225px dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbc6W.png)

What I want to do is to keep the 'solid' appearance of the ghost image even if the element's dimensions exceed 225px. Is there any way to prevent this "transparency gradient" to apply?

NOTE : I am working on Edge but I tried on Chrome and FireFox and the problem occurs there too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hi, I am currently facing this nightmarish issue too with ghost images!!! did you manage to solve this?? this is driving me crazy!